# Light bulb LED equivalent of a CFL (Compact Fluorescent Lamp)

Tags: led, light, compact-fluorescent-lamp, comparison

If I have a CFL light bulb of 100W what would be (how many watts ) its equivalent in LED.

In the place where I live LEDs have taken over and CFLs are no longer available, but I need stron bright lights and with LEDs it ranges from 6 to 14 watts.
While searching online i saw phillips selling LEDs with equivalent characteristics to CFLs. how can I do that by myself ? with local LED light bulbs available here ?

what matters to me is the brightness.

**EDIT**
Is there anyway I can somehow evaluate how bright and LED light will be if I'm given only something like 14W and the voltage .?

Comment: 100W CFL is a monster lightbulb... Anyway, brightness is a subjective characteristic, based on spectrum and human vision specifics, while power is objective.

Comment: @EugeneSh.yeah its for  specific purpose.   how do you compare 100W LED to 100W CFL ?

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's a 100W CFL, and not 100W-equivalent? A lot of CFL and LED lights are rated in their "equivalent" power, which is just the power of an incandescent bulb of the same brightness (which means that a 100W-equivalent CFL and a 100W-equivalent LED lamp would have the same brightness)

Comment: The reason I ask this is because of what @EugeneSh. said: a 100W CFL is a _very_ powerful lightbulb, and not something I'd generally expect to see on the general consumer market.

Comment: To compare on equal ground you should be looking for the lumens for each bulb and the color balance ie off-white, blue-white etc

Comment: I really doubt it is a 100W CFL. That power density is the one you would not even be able to find in a 4ft fluorescent tube. It’s more likely to be a 100W incandescent equivalent which is probably <20W.

Comment: @Hearth honestly am not really sure. but how can I check that ?  because sometimes its not mentionned,  check out this light it's says 135W wich technology is it ?   https://www.banggood.com/Wholesale-E27-5500K-135W-Photo-Video-Photography-Daylight-Lighting-Studio-Lamp-Bulb-p-45039.html?rmmds=search&cur_warehouse=CN

Comment: I guess you guys are right i don't really know they just write 50 60 or 100W on the package big companies like philips take the time to detail everything but not all companies do.

Comment: @EdgarBrown with all that you said, is there anyway I can somehow evaluate how bright and LED light will be if am given only something like 14W and the voltage ?   another doubt: is possible for 2 LED light with same Watts have different brightness ?

Comment: You should be looking for a lumen rating, not a watt rating. the lumen rating is a direct metric of how bright the bulb is.

Comment: Products on sites like Banggood, Ebay, AliExpress, etc have hugely exaggerated specifications anyway. I wouldn't trust any specs I find on there. And, while we're at it, I wouldn't trust any product from there on mains power.

Comment: @Xsmael you can derive/find some rules of thumb that would put you in the ballpark by looking at the reputable manufacturers that actually provide specifications (è.g., average lumens/watt for each technology). But efficiency (particularly of LEDs) is very variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SolarMike said, you can't compare the actual power consumption of the bulbs nor can you rely on the manufacturer's claims of "Equivalent to xx watts". If you only care about brightness, and not color, then compare the number of lumens provided by each bulb.

No, you cannot determine (exact) brightness by looking at actual power consumption, and voltage is completely irrelevant. Two bulbs that consume the same amount of power at the same supply voltage may provide different levels of "brightness".

Comment: You are certainly right but the issue is that a lot of manufacturers do not mention the lumens especillay for light bulbs. what they give the most are voltage or watts and consumption

Comment: Can you define what you need better in terms of Lumens and area covered?  You can also use 48" tubes that are better than LEDs for under cabinets over counters. with same 30k~60kh MTBF and good lumens per watt ( 88L/W) with tri-phospor  better spectrum and no flicker or sound and very low mercury amalgam.

Comment: Don't buy bulbs from anyone who won't tell you the lumens produced by the bulb.